# How to get first and last related event without having to do extra subqueries?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables: `Customers` and `CustomerEvents`. Each customer can have 0 or more events.

I'm working on a report that's supposed to look something like this:

```
CustomerName     | FirstEventDate | FirstEventMessage   | LastEventDate | LastEventText
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Customers 'R' US | 2018-01-01     | Customer registered | 2018-04-06    | Customer Quit
```

The actual query is going to be a lot larger than that, but this is the general gist of it.

If I only needed the dates, I could easily do it using aggregates:

```
SELECT 
    c.Name AS ContactName
    , MAX(e.DateTime) AS FirstEventDate
    , '???' AS FirstEventMessage
    , MIN(e.DateTime) AS FirstEventDate
    , '???' AS FirstEventMessage
FROM Contacts c
    LEFT JOIN CustomerEvents e ON e.ContactId = c.Id
GROUP BY c.Name
```

Unfortunately, that leaves out the corresponding messages.

I've managed to solve it using a subquery for each message, but that gets *super* expensive, so I was wondering if there's another approach you'd suggest. The full query is more complex than the example will have joins on different kinds of events, each displaying the date and message of the first and last event.

Comment: With SQL-Server 2012 the window functions [FIRST_VALUE() and LAST_VALUE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql) were introduced.

Comment: Prior to SQL Server 2012, there's a complicated trick you can use that involves concatenating your desired values as `BINARY`, applying the aggregate to them and then unpacking the result. It's not pretty, but it's a guaranteed single pass.

Comment: @Shnugo that worked! If you write up an answer based on that I'll make sure you get all the imaginary Internet points.

Comment: @PetterBrodin This might be important: Add the `c.Id` to your `GROUP BY`... What if two Contacts have the same name?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. The actual query is a lot more complex and is dealing with ID as well as name, I just chose that as my one column when simplifying the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you asked me, to create an answer out of my comment, here you are:

With version 2012 Microsoft introduced some new windowing functions. Usefull for you are [`FIRST_VALUE()` and `LAST_VALUE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql). Both need an `OVER()` clause to specify the sort order and - if needed - a partitioning rule.

This should work (but I do not know your tables and data):

```
SELECT 
    c.Name AS ContactName
    , MIN(e.DateTime) AS FirstEventDate
    , FIRST_VALUE(e.EventMessage) OVER(ORDER BY e.DateTime) AS FirstEventMessage
    , MAX(e.DateTime) AS LastEventDate
    , LAST_VALUE(e.EventMessage) OVER(ORDER BY e.DateTime) AS LastventMessage
FROM Contacts c
    LEFT JOIN CustomerEvents e ON e.ContactId = c.Id
GROUP BY c.Id,c.Name;
```

But be warned: If your `e.DateTime` is not unique (per `Contact`), you will get a random "first" value...

**Hints**

- Make sure to have indexes on `DateTime` and `ContactId` and
- add the `c.Id` to your `GROUP BY`

An alternative was to replace the `LEFT JOIN CustomerEvents` with a row-wise executed correlated sub-query. This has the advantage, that you can be sure, that both (and more) values are taken from the same row.

```
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 e.[DateTime],e.[EventMessage]  
             FROM CustomerEvents AS e
             WHERE e.ContactId=c.Id
             ORDER BY e.EventMessage ASC) AS FirstEvent
--same with DESC
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 e.[DateTime],e.[EventMessage]  
             FROM CustomerEvents AS e
             WHERE e.ContactId=c.Id
             ORDER BY e.EventMessage DESC) AS LastEvent
```

Then use the columns in your query like

```
 FirstEvent.DateTime AS FirstDateTime
,FirstEvent.EventMessage AS FirstMessage
,LastEvent.DateTime AS LastDateTime
,LastEvent.EventMessage AS LastMessage
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this CTE approach, adjust the columns to SELECT clause according to you need.

```
;WITH CTE
AS(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.Name ORDER BY e.DateTime) AS RowAsc,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.Name ORDER BY e.DateTime DESC) AS RowDesc
    FROM Contacts c
        LEFT JOIN CustomerEvents e ON e.ContactId = c.Id    
)
SELECT 
    c1.*
    , c2.*
FROM CTE c1
INNER JOIN CTE c2 ON c1.Name = c2.Name
    AND c1.RowAsc = 1 
    AND c2.RowDesc = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Approach

```
SELECT 
    c.Name AS CustomerName
    , MAX(e.DateTime) AS LastEventDate
    , B.Message AS FirstEventMessage
    , MIN(e.DateTime) AS FirstEventDate
    , D.Message AS FirstEventMessage
FROM #Customers c
    LEFT JOIN #CustomerEvents e ON e.CustomerId = c.Id
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT A.CustomerId, A.Message
    FROM
        (
        SELECT 
            CustomerId, Message, Row_Number()over(Partition By CustomerId order by DATETIME DESC) as No
        FROM
            #CustomerEvents 
        ) A
    WHERE
        A.No = 1
    ) B ON B.CustomerId = C.Id
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT A.CustomerId, A.Message
    FROM
        (
        SELECT 
            CustomerId, Message, Row_Number()over(Partition By CustomerId order by DATETIME) as No
        FROM
            #CustomerEvents 
        ) A
    WHERE
        A.No = 1
    ) d ON d.CustomerId = C.Id
GROUP BY 
    c.Name, B.Message, D.Message
```